# translation in breadcrumb angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, breadcrumbs, angular-i18n

I have following routes and want to add translation for breadcrumb labels.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'crisis-center', data: {breadcrumb: 'crisis center'}, component: CrisisListComponent },
{ path: 'hero/:id',     data: {breadcrumb: 'hero'}, component: HeroDetailComponent },
{
  path: 'heroes',
  component: HeroListComponent,
  data: { breadcrumb: 'Heroes List' }
},
{ path: '',
  redirectTo: '/heroes',
  data: {breadcrumb: 'Heros'},
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{ path: '**',       data: {breadcrumb: 'Page not found'}, component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

I searched around and haven't found any thing. I guess I probably can use `i18n en.json` file, but all examples for templates. Is there a way to translate breadcrumb into other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ngx-translate/core](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core). Just import it, define `en.json` file and in your breadcrumb component you can do it by injecting

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}
```

and translate it in your component (notice it's synchronous method, you can check how to make it asynchronous in clear documentation):

```
this.translate.instant(breadcrumbTitle)
```

or in a template like this:

```
<span>{{ breadcrumbTitle | translate }}</span>
```

Comment: I have implemented a lot of translation in templates. Is there a way to inject "TranslateService" in routes?

Comment: I don't think there is any good practice solution and it should not be done here because you will have to make it for each data property. You should pass code from `en.json` and translate it in your breadcrumb component.

Comment: I normally have several files, en.json, fr.json, and others. However, all breadcrumb example have data in routes.

Comment: And what are you doing with that breadcrumb data in your component? Please add an example to question. Why can't you translate it here?

Comment: Breadcrumb data adds route locations for a web site. Here is an example.http://brianflove.com/2016/10/23/angular2-breadcrumb-using-router/

Comment: I probably can inject translate service in that component. Is there a way to read the en.json or other file from a typescript code?

Comment: In your breadcrumb component just use `<a [routerLink]="[breadcrumb.url, breadcrumb.params]">{{breadcrumb.label | translate}}</a>`. It will automatically take translations from `/assets/i18n/en.json`. If you want to switch language write for example `translate.use('fr')`.

Comment: I think I figured the problem. Although your answer didn't provide a direct solution, but is very helpful in solving my problem.

Comment: @user3097695 If you have your own solution, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Angular 7+ Breadcrumb Component – pp-breadcrumbs translate with @ngx-translat
// in app-routing.module:
/*
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    
path: 'cr', loadChildren: () => import('./cr/cr.module').then(m => m.CrModule), data: { breadcrumbs: 'Request' }
  }]

//in app.component:

this.breadcrumbsService.postProcess = (breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[]) => {
      breadcrumbs.map(b => {
        b.text = translate.instant('breadcrumbs.' + b.text)
      })
      breadcrumbs.unshift({ text: translate.instant('breadcrumbs.home'), path: '/' });
      return breadcrumbs;
    };
//in he.json :
 "breadcrumbs": {
    "home": "בית",
    "Request": "בקשות"
  }


*/
```